# Help with a Given step that goes to a page and as a logged in user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

My scenerio looks like:

```
Given I am on the homepage
As a member
When I follow "new post"
..
..
```

In my web_steps.rb I added:

```
When /^As a (.+)$/ do |type|
  @user = Factory(:user, type)
end
```

My factories are in:

```
/spec/factories.rb
/spec/factories/user.rb
```

How do I reference my factories.rb into my web_steps.rb page?
Am I doing this correctly?  Now this instance variable @user is the variable that my controller checks to see if it is authenticated correct?

I'm getting this error currently:

```
features/create_post.feature: Lexing error on line 8: ' As a member'.
```

**What is wrong with my 'As a member' line?**

**Update**

I noticed I had:

When /^As a

I changed it to:

As /^a

now I get:

```
undefined method `As' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'As' is not valid in a cucumber scenario as far as I know.

Your lines should start with 'Given', 'When', 'Then', or 'And'.

Your scenario should probably look more like

```
Given I am logged in as 'User'
When I go to the homepage
And I follow "New post"
Then ...
```

Comment: if a given step is failing, how can I see the html to debug?

Comment: 'Then show me the page' as a step saves and opens the page, although if your given step is actually creating an exception then test execution won't actually get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write web steps that instantiate factories, i use [Pickle](https://github.com/ianwhite/pickle) for this.  Pickle is nice, because you don't have to futz with your factories at all in cucumber.  It defines generic steps for creating any given factory object (model), as well as steps for finding model objects and other things.

Ryan Bates has a created a [screenscast on pickle](http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber) as well.  Rails screencasts are a nice post-lunch office tradition around our place!

Ok, good luck,

ian.

Comment: I think i would give up on the 'As' syntax and just write my step like: `Given /^a member$/ do`.  Another approach would be to put "member" in quotes as the type that you want your factory to instantiate, i.e. `Given /^a user who is a ("([^"]*)"$/ do |type|`.